# Various calendars in the ASP.NET Calendar Control

Tags: asp.net, calendar, globalization

I need to create an ASP.NET page that displays a Calendar control which shows a specific calendar based on value selected in a drop down. 
Currently I need to display HebrewCalendar and the regualr (gregorian) calendar, but in the future I'll probably need others.
Of course I can't use the Regional Settings of Windows or the globalization definition in web.config since the required calendar is set in runtime.
How can I display various calendars in a Calendar control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is you'll need to set the Culture of the current thread, and (for some locales like Hebrew) also need to set the Calendar within that Culture.

The self-contained code sample below illustrates how to do this.  This approach of course may affect other controls's localized text. If this is a problem-- and you only want to localize the Calendar control and leave the rest in English-- then you can do the following:

- derive a class from ASP.NET's Calendar control and override the Render() method.
- in your Render() implementation, save the current thread's culture/UICulture, then reset the culture and calendar of the current thread using the code below, then call the base class's Render(), then restore the culture/UICulture of the curren thread
- use that class, instead of the regular ASP.NET calendar, in your ASPX page.

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Globalization"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic"%>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Choose a language and calendar: <asp:DropDownList ID="LocaleChoice" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US" Selected="True">English</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-MX">Español</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="de-DE">Deutsch</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="he-IL|HebrewCalendar">Hebrew (Hebrew Calendar)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="he-IL|GregorianCalendar">Hebrew (Gregorian Calendar)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ar-SA|HijriCalendar">Arabic (Hijri Calendar)</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="ar-SA|GregorianCalendar">Arabic (Gregorian Calendar)</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br /><br />
    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">

    Dictionary<string, System.Globalization.Calendar> Calendars =
        new Dictionary<string, System.Globalization.Calendar>()
        {
            {"GregorianCalendar", new GregorianCalendar()},
            {"HebrewCalendar", new HebrewCalendar()},
            {"HijriCalendar", new HijriCalendar()},
            {"JapaneseCalendar", new JapaneseCalendar()},
            {"JulianCalendar", new JulianCalendar()},
            {"KoreanCalendar", new KoreanCalendar()},
            {"TaiwanCalendar", new TaiwanCalendar()},
            {"ThaiBuddhistCalendar", new ThaiBuddhistCalendar ()}
        };

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Request.Form["LocaleChoice"] != null)
        {
            string selected = Request.Form["LocaleChoice"];
            string[] calendarSetting = selected.Split('|');
            string selectedLanguage = calendarSetting[0];

            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);

            if (calendarSetting.Length > 1)
            {
                string selectedCalendar = calendarSetting[1];
                var cal = culture.Calendar;
                if (Calendars.TryGetValue(selectedCalendar, out cal))
                    culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cal;
            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        }
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need per-calendar culture customization have a look at [BaseCalendar](http://basecalendar.codeplex.com/) (there's a demo included that handles this scenario). Changing the current thread's culture could have side-effects in other places. BaseCalendar allows you to specify a culture for a calendar without changing the current thread's culture.